# subversion with secured code

Tags: git, svn, version-control

We want to use version control (SVN or GIT), with the option of only authorizing the developer to edit some files and commit, then test on the online server.

Is there any solution that can do that?

Comment: The answers is "yes". :) Note that the questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion supports [path-based authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) with No Access / Read Only / Read Write access rules.

If you consider using VisualSVN Server on Windows, read the [VisualSVN Server Getting Started | Configuring User Permissions](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions) section. It is possible to configure access rules through VisualSVN Server Manager MMC console, VisualSVN Repository Configurator (tool for non-administrators) and using [VisualSVN Server PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) cmdlets.

Read the article [KB33: Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) to learn more about the authorization mechanism in Subversion and VisualSVN Server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check it out ^^  +1

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and Netbeans, and I want to build a team of developers who will have access to some files.

Comment: I guess that you may want to build a simple svnserve-based server on your Linux machine. See https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/svnserve/

Comment: I've already built an svnserve and I imported my project to it. But the problem is that I got stuck with Netbeans.

Comment: Netbeans asks me to install libapache2-svn, but I get this message : 
`Unable to locate package libapache2-svn`,  That's why I wanted to find another solution.

Comment: @SmootQ Sorry, I don't have much experience with Netbeans. I would recommend that you ask a new question on StackOverflow specific to that issue in NetBeans. Don't miss the SO Asking help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help, I just wrote this question in a hurry as I was under pressure and stress. Thanks again +1

Comment: @SmootQ Since the question you asked originally has been solved, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar question.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT , I know thank you ^^ .. I tried to do that the other day and it said that I cannot mark as best answer before 1 min

Answer (score 0):

yep, both (SVN or GIT) achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply